# Do I have to create a state ref for every input, or can I use 1 state ref that is an object in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to create 2 inputs that are binded to 2 ref states and then when I click a button, send that data to the parent component. Currently I have this:

```
<script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue';

    const name = ref('');
    const surname = ref('');
</script>

<template>
    <div class="user-input-container">
        <div class="user-input">
            <p>Name</p>
            <input
                :value="name"
                @input="event => name = event.target.value"
            >
        </div>
        <div class="user-input">
            <p>Surname</p>
            <input
                :value="surname "
                @input="event => surname = event.target.value"
            >
        </div>
    </div>
    <p @click="$emit('onUserInput', { name, surname })">Click me</p>
</template>
```

I am wondering if I could do something like this in order to not create multiple refs:

```
<script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue';

    const user = ref({
        name: '',
        surname: ''
    })

</script>

<template>
    <div class="user-input-container">
        <div class="user-input">
            <p>Name</p>
            <input
                :value="user.name"
                @input="event => user.name = event.target.value"
            >
        </div>
        <div class="user-input">
            <p>Surame</p>
            <input
                :value="user.surname "
                @input="event => user.surname = event.target.value"
            >
        </div>
    </div>
    <p @click="$emit('onUserInput', user)">Click me</p>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches are good, but you should minimize the code amount using `v-model` directive:

```html
<script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue';

    const name = ref('');
    const surname = ref('');
</script>

<template>
    <div class="user-input-container">
        <div class="user-input">
            <p>Name</p>
             <input v-model="name"/>
        </div>
        <div class="user-input">
            <p>Surname</p>
            <input v-model="surname"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p @click="$emit('onUserInput', { name, surname })">Click me</p>
</template>
```